# Counting Empty Columns in Rows

Tags: php, counting

I have a property table and it has six columns. Users upload photo and image name is stored in the column.

***Now I want to count the number of columns for each row which are empty.***

I am already able to do that but the code looks too long, I want to write efficient code, is there a way to rewrite the following efficiently.

```
while($data=$select->fetch()){ 

    $imagecounter=0;
    if ($data['property_image1'] !== "" && $data['property_image2'] !== "" && $data['property_image3'] !== "" && $data['property_image4'] !== "" && $data['property_image5'] !== "" && $data['property_image6'] !== "") {
     echo $imagecounter=6; 
    } else if ($data['property_image1'] !== "" && $data['property_image2'] !== "" && $data['property_image3'] !== "" && $data['property_image4'] !== "" && $data['property_image5'] !== "") {
     echo $imagecounter=5; 
    } else if ($data['property_image1'] !== "" && $data['property_image2'] !== "" && $data['property_image3'] !== "" && $data['property_image4'] !== "") {
     echo $imagecounter=4; 
    } else if ($data['property_image1'] !== "" && $data['property_image2'] !== "" && $data['property_image3'] !== "") {
     echo $imagecounter=3; 
    } else if ($data['property_image1'] !== "" && $data['property_image2'] !== "") {
     echo $imagecounter=2; 
    } else if ($data['property_image1'] !== "") {
     echo $imagecounter=1; 
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***You can do it like below:-***

```
while($data=$select->fetch()){ 
  $data1 = array($data['property_image1'],$data['property_image2'],$data['property_image3'],$data['property_image4'],$data['property_image5'],$data['property_image6']);
  $count = count($data1); // count of original array
  $count1 = count(array_filter($data1)); // remove empty indexes and count the values

  echo "empty columns number is :-".($count-$count1);
}
```

Note:- `$count1` is count of non-empty values

Comment: There is a lot more data coming, there are many more columns, but i want to check only these six columns...

Comment: what if we wanted to get the result as - how many fields are not empty...

Comment: echo $count1 will do it.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
while($data=$select->fetch()):
    $imagecounter = 0;
    for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++)
        if(!empty($data["property_image$i"]))
            $imagecounter++;

    echo $imagecounter;
endwhile;
```

Comment: not good code in the sense of time consuming because of two loops

Answer (score 1):

does the column name has its rule?

assuming it's 'property_image{number}'

```
while($row=$result->fetch()) {
    $count = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<6; $i++) {
        if($row['property_image'.$i]==NULL)
            $count++;
    }
    echo "empty columns number is :-".($count);
}
```

code is not tested.
let me know if it doesnt work